# Opposite of additive

Tags: antonyms

Additive as in *additive manufacturing*, i.e. in 3D printing for example. How can traditional processing methods, like a lathe for example, be described? I believe I have seen *ablative* being used in this context, but I can't find it being used like that on the net. Is *subtractive* the right choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the term **subtractive** is used with manufacturing to describe [that](http://www.approto.com/Media-Center/Additive-vs-Subtractive-Manufacturing--Which-is-Ri.aspx).